# SimpleInjector with Sitecore and WebApi controller does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sitecore, simple-injector

We have integrated SimpleInjector (`4.4.x`) in our `Sitecore 8.2` [Helix](https://helix.sitecore.net/) project.

We have a Dependency Injection project in our [Foundation Layer](https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html#foundation-layer), which consists of the following pipeline:

```
public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    // register app dependencies (omitted for readability)

    // get assemblies of our application
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(assemblies);
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration,assemblies);

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Also as described in [this post](https://ctor.io/one-way-to-implement-dependency-injection-for-sitecore-habitat/), the pipeline processor is implemented in the Sitecore `initialize` pipeline:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initializeDependencyInjection/>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Company.Foundation.Example.DependencyInjectionProcessor, Company.Foundation.Example"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, both `ASP.NET MVC` and `WebApi` are used (`.NET 4.6`). 
Our solution consists only of MVC controllers. What we are trying to achieve is introducing `WebApi` in our solution. When adding the following controller, all works well:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/hello")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But when I add a dependency (and also register) e.g.:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Hello { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Hello => "Hello World!";
}

public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public HelloController(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/hello")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_foo.Hello);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception message in runtime when doing the HTTP request:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HelloController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

InnerException:

> System.ArgumentException: Type 'Company.Feature.Example.HelloController' does not have a default constructor

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

What strikes me weird is that `container.Verify()` does not throw any exceptions or warnings. When debugging, I can see that the `HelloController` is registered in the `Root Registrations` of the `container`.

Also the binding redirects for `WebApi` are set in the `web.config` of the root project:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: What I can see from the exception details is that for some reason (that is unclear to me), the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` isn't used by the `DefaultHttpControllerActivator`, because the `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` will never return `null` when an `IHttpController` derivate is requested by the `DefaultHttpControllerActivator`. Perhaps the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` is overridden again later. You will have to debug this to find out why this happens.

Comment: Hi @Steven your timing is exactly on the moment as I've stumbled upon this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/webapi-failing-to-resolve-dependencies  
Indeed later in the Sitecore pipeline the entity `GlobalConfiguration` is overridden.  
I've applied the patch and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/webapi-failing-to-resolve-dependencies) and as [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) suggested in the comment, the dependency resolver gets overridden later in the Sitecore pipeline.

I've extended the `initialize` pipeline:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initializeDependencyInjection/>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Company.Foundation.Example.DependencyInjectionProcessor, Company.Foundation.Example"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
        <processor type=" Company.Foundation.Example.WebApiDependenceResolverProcessor, Company.Foundation.Example"
                   patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services.Pipelines.Initialize.WebApiInitializer, Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Where I've also added the following processor:

```
public class WebApiDependenceResolverProcessor
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        // retrieve container here

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Here we set the dependecy resolver for `WebApi` *after* Sitecore resets it.